# Read text file data

Tags: d

In C++, `istream& operator>>` can be used to read data "as in text". What is the equivalent in D?

My attempt:

**input.txt**

```
c 1033
90.432
```

**input_test.d**

```
import std.stdio;
import std.stream;

void main()
{
    auto inputFile = new BufferedFile("input.txt");
    char c;
    int i;
    double d;

    inputFile.read(c);
    inputFile.read(i);
    inputFile.read(d);
    writeln(c, '\t', i, '\t', d);
}
```

**Output**

```
c   858796320   4.90559e-62
```

Comment: BTW, I think what that code does is read in a char, int and double *in binary form*. That is, the first read gets one byte, the second gobbles 4 bytes and the last 8 and interprets each bit sequence as the related type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D has lots of ways of reading data from files to make various use cases convenient. Here are some:

- [std.file.read](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#read) for reading the contents of a file into an untyped array of bytes.
- [std.file.readText](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#readText) for reading the contents of a file into a string.
- The members of the [InputStream](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stream.html#InputStream) interface which you've already discovered.
- [std.stdio.file:readln](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#readln) for reading lines from a file. Also see readf in the same structure.
- [std.stdio.file:byLine](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#byLine) (also byChunk) for reading lines or arbitrary sized blobs.

Based on your specific case, you'll probably want to use [slurp](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#slurp) or [readf](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#readf). Your other option is to read lines and split them into the fields you want, then use std.conv.to to parse the textual representation:

```
double d = to!double(somestring);
```

In summary, if every line has the same format, slurp is the nicest way to go. Otherwise, you'll have to decide what will be most convenient for you.

Comment: The output is not what I want. The `int` and `double` are incorrect. Back to your suggestions, suppose I use `byLine`. I should then use `splitter` and the `std.conv` utilities?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I like slurp a lot, but if the format varies line-to-line, you'll probably need to go with manually splitting and converting the pieces.

Comment: I tried `readf`, but something went wrong (also I'm new to the format syntax). Thank you for the `slurp` suggestion, I didn't know about that.